SteamWorks WebAPIのICloudServiceインターフェイスが動作しない
Webサイト側でゲームデータを取得したい。
そのためにはICloudService InterfaceのEnumerateUserFilesを使う必要があると思うのですが、それを使うためにはaccessTokenが必要です。
しかし、SteamのOAuth2.0を使った認証に必要なClientIDが見つかりません。
この問題を解決する方法をどなたかご教授いただけると幸いです。

以下に StreamWorks OAuth についてのドキュメントがあります。

https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview/oauth

これによると、「OAuthの使用にはまず、ValveからClient IDを取得する必要があります。」とあります。
また、「初回セットアップの際、次の情報をValveに提供する必要があります：<中略> 返信時に、Valveは実装に必要なClient IDを割り当てます。」とあります。
これらからすると、Valve 社への問い合わせが必要となるのではないでしょうか？

ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
返信時~の文言を見落としていました、
一度Valveに問い合わせをしてみます。
